# Border and background moves when you download a file

Tags: html, css

my border is moving when you have the download file ?tab? open on chrome (haven't tested it with any other browser). This completely destroys the look of my website, the text is still in the same position but the border and background moves up a bit.... I have tried every position but it didn't work... I'm really annoyed at this problem, any help would be appreciated.

here is the css code

```
.classA {
    border: 5px solid;

    text-align: left;
    line-height: 0.5;
    
    position: fixed;
    height: 11%;
    top: 110px;
    right: 5px;
    left: 5px;

}
```

Comment: Can you provide an online demo if you don't mind? 
It's hard to recognize " is moving "

Comment: https://imgur.com/XDAHk85 @WatsonChen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply how Chrome works when you start a download. You can work around this with css, but please provide us with some code or a demo with what you've already tried.

A quick thought:

The first thing that comes to mind is to not use percentage for your height property, since it takes 11% of the current height, which depletes when you get the download bar in your screen, since the download bar takes up space of your screen.

If you give the class a fixed height, for example 100 pixels, you will see the class won't decrease in height.

So the code will be:

```
.classA {
    border: 5px solid;

    text-align: left;
    line-height: 0.5;
    
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px; /* just an example, does not need to be 100px */
    top: 110px;
    right: 5px;
    left: 5px;

}
```